# How do I toggle Altium HUD Differential Pair info?

Tags: pcb, altium

For some reason, my HUD in Altium doesn't show me info of the differential pair that I'm hovering above or when I select it. How is this toggled?[image: HUD]

Comment: You'll probably get better support here: https://discord.me/altium

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, but I'm using a work computer and discord is blocked on our systems

Comment: You might not be doing yourself a big favour having it blocked. You can get plenty of free libraries and I can personally vouch for the guy running it.

Comment: @Andyaka unfortunately, that's not my call to make. I'm just an employee, I don't have a say in what they block here at the office...

Comment: I bet they'll unblock it if you ask nicely.